# Magento native profiler works for debugging? How do i debug observers?

Tags: magento

Unable to find how profiler works in magento.

How do i debug observers in magento and those looks so confusing. Do we have any online tools available to debug observers in magento?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by debugging observers/blocks? Profiler is used to see the performance of various parts on a single page. Also, I can recommend the following module, which enhances the profiler and gives you a lot more useful information: https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_Profiler

Comment: I mean i want to see what observers/blocks are running currently.